# Errors when running python gdal.grid with basic parameters

Tags: python, gdal, arcgis-10.0

There are a few problems when I run the following code.

1. Image comes out flipped vertically, even though lat lon is input correctly
2. I have to run the code twice for it to run properly (so wierrd)
3. I also get the following errors:

```
    ERROR 4: `result.tif' not recognized as a supported file format.
    ERROR 4: Unable to open result.tif to obtain file list.
    ERROR 1: Deleting result.tif failed:
    Permission denied
```

I use the following data in the points.csv:

```
    lat lon value
    39.545  -75.78  0.001034494
    39.555  -75.78  0.001033509
    39.565  -75.78  0.001032392
    39.575  -75.78  0.001001829
    39.585  -75.78  0.00094428
    39.595  -75.78  0.000940016
    39.605  -75.78  0.000897172
    39.615  -75.78  0.000896742
    39.625  -75.78  0.000896021
```

And here is the code...

```
# create the csv and vrt file
vrt_file = """<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
        <SrcDataSource>points.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat" z="value"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>"""
with open("points.vrt", "w") as f:
    f.write(vrt_file.strip())

# perform gridding and RGB rastering
# for some reason this has to run twice????
gdal.AllRegister()
gdal.Grid('result.tif',
               'points.vrt',
               format='GTiff',
               outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32,
               algorithm='linear:radius=0.5',
               zfield='value')

# plot, comes out flipped on accident
im = gdal.Open('result.tif').ReadAsArray()
im = plt.imshow(im)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by assigning `gdal.Grid()` to a variable, like `output = gdal.Grid()` and then immediately assign that variable to 'None', so after you run your model, `output = None`.

It's apparently a 'gotcha' when using `gdal.Grid()` in Python. This prevents the error of having to run the model twice and not have that other error where it says that your result is not a TIFF file.